# Override IEnumerable<T> set property;

Tags: c#

I'm implementing `IEnumerable<T>` for a type as follows;

```
public class AType: IEnumerable<T>
```

How can I can get control of the type's set property when a client assigns an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` to an instance of AType? Is this possible or do I have to go through a public member of type `IEnumerable<T>`;

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Surely you would assign an instance of `AType` or an instance of a type derived from `AType` to an `AType` variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "the type's set properity"?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create an implicit/explicit cast override to convert an `IEnumerable` to an `AType`?

Comment: @John yes thats what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

It's not common that you actually need to make your own enumerable type.  I think what you really want is a class like so:

```
public class Foo<T>
{ 
    IEnumerable<T> _aTypes;
    public IEnumerable<T> ATypes 
    {
         get { return _aTypes; }
         set 
         {
             //do your custom logic
             this._aTypes = value;
         }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice was going to be to use an [cast operator override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) but I'd forgotten that you can't use an interface as a source in this case.

That leads me to think the best solution would be to add a second constructor to handle your case:

```
public class AType<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    public AType() // parameterless constructor if you need it
    {
    }

    public AType(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        // use data from source to initialize AType
    }

    // implementation of IEnumerable<T> interface goes here
}
```